# When event AppointmentItem.Unload fire ?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm working with an VSTO add-in for Outlook 2007 in C#/.Net. I try to release the reference of objects after save them. First, I try to do that in event Unload with
`Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item)`
but it don't work all time.

I find on internet that Outlook had an event AfterWrite fire right after event Write(event fire when user save an item in Outlook). But I don't know how to catch this event ?

So, I want to ask how I can release the reference or catch the AfterWrite event.

Thank you,

Comment: It depends how you are getting the reference to the item in the first place.  Is it from NameSpace.GetItemFromID, Explorer.Selection, an Items collection, Inspector.CurrentItem, etc. Please show your full code

Comment: Thank you for your respond ! I load it from Explorer.Selection in an UIExplorer listener. As it is a project of my enterprise, I don't be allowed to upload the full code, sorry :(.

Answer (score 0):

The Unload event only occurs after the Close event, so the message must be opened in an Inspector for that to be effective.

If you are setting a reference to the item from Explorer.Selection, then just release the item object when you are done with it. If you need to keep a reference to that variable at a higher scope, then you will have to release it when the Explorer.SelectionChange event fires.